# Checking the equality of types involving existentials in Scala

Tags: scala, existential-type

I'm writing a function of the form

```
def test[A,B](a: A, b: B)(implicit eq: A =:= B): Unit = ...
```

where I require an evidence that types `A` and `B` are the same.

I would expect calls of the form `test(a,a)` to compile for any `a`, but it seems not to be the case when `a`'s type involves existentials, like in

```
case class Foo[T](c: T)
val l = List(Foo(1), Foo(1.0F), Foo(0.0)) // Inferred type: List[Foo[_ >: Double with Float with Int <: AnyVal]]

test(l.head, l.head) // Does not compile, error like: Cannot prove that Foo[_7] =:= Foo[_7].
```

So my question is: am I mis-using `=:=`? Or could it be a bug? Or a fundamental limitation of existentials? Or a limitation of their implementation?

### Context

I'm testing the return type of a function `f` involving dependent types.
I expect it to return the same type for `a` and `b` in `val a = f(...); val b = f(...)`, thus I call `test(a, b)`. If `a` and `b`'s types involve existentials, even `test(a,a)` and `test(b,b)` don't compile, as described above.

Answer (score 3):

Implicit =:= works fine for existential types

```
scala> implicitly[Foo[_ <: Int] =:= Foo[_ <: Int]]
res0: =:=[Foo[_ <: Int],Foo[_ <: Int]] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[Foo[_ <: Int] =:= Foo[_]]
<console>:10: error: Cannot prove that Foo[_ <: Int] =:= Foo[_].
              implicitly[Foo[_ <: Int] =:= Foo[_]]
                        ^
```

The problem is scala loses existential type when resolving implicit for function call - A and B are not inferred here (that's why you see _7 denotation and no implicits are found).

```
def test[A,B](a: A, b: B)(implicit eq: A =:= B)
```

It can be solved with type alias:

```
scala> case class Foo[A](a: A) {type X = A}
defined class Foo

scala> val l = List(Foo(1), Foo(1.0F), Foo(0.0)) // Inferred type: List[Foo[_ >: Double with Float with Int <: AnyVal]]
l: List[Foo[_ >: Double with Float with Int <: AnyVal]] = List(Foo(1), Foo(1.0), Foo(0.0)) 

scala> val k = l.head
k: Foo[_ >: Double with Float with Int <: AnyVal] = Foo(1)

scala> implicitly[k.X =:= k.X]
res15: =:=[_ >: Double with Float with Int <: AnyVal, _ >: Double with Float with Int <: AnyVal] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[k.X =:= _ >: Double with Float with Int <: AnyVal]
res16: =:=[_ >: Double with Float with Int <: AnyVal, _ >: Double with Float with Int <: AnyVal] = <function1>
```

But keep in mind that even types with similar signature, but from different Foo's will be different (because it's path-dependent types) - existential types are so existential!

Comment: Good answer. But I still dont understand why it fails in the question case. What do you mean by this: `it becomes unbound here`

Comment: Moreover if this works: `implicitly[Foo[_ >: Double with Float with Int <: AnyVal] =:= Foo[_ >: Double with Float with Int <: AnyVal]]` why doesn't that?

Comment: test function doing some kind of compile-time erasure for A,B when they're existential (i think it's possible to fix it in compiler) so A and B becomes _7 - and there is no implicits are possible for such internal existential types, so implicitly[_7 =:= _7] fails. In your example existential type is known - so it works fine.

Comment: `def t[A,B](n:A, x:B) = println(n+" "+x)
t(l.head, l.head)` works. I still dont fully understand the reason in comments :). From what it appears to me, it looks to be a compiler caveat. 
`

Comment: _n is a non inferred type denotation - it was just not inferred when resolving implicit. Actually it doesn't matters what you call inside a function - because even implicitly will not work for generic types.

Comment: On the other hand - seems that A and B still can be inferred before implicit check - so maybe it's really a bug or not implemented feature - seems like philosophical question :)